# How to get the distance between 2 objects? (LUA)

Tags: lua

```
game:GetService('RunService').RenderStepped:connect(function()
    if ENABLED then
         local lol = game.Workspace.Zombies:GetChildren()
         local me = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character
         for index, lol in pairs(lol) do
    if lol:IsA("Model") then
    local AIM = lol:FindFirstChild(_G.AIM_AT)
    if AIM then
    CC.CoordinateFrame = CFrame.new(CC.CoordinateFrame.p, AIM.CFrame.p)
         end
end
end
end
end
end)
```

How to get the distance between "me" and "AIM"?
I've tried everthing.. :/

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Magnitude
This is what it says on the wiki,
Here is an Exmaple:

```
local distance = (part1.Position - part2.Position).magnitude
```

print(distance) would return the distance (as a value such as int/float)